# Is countDocuments() speed in DocumentDB depends on document size?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I found that countDocuments() take different time in different copy of the same db. The case is next:

- counts documents same (about 70k)
- structure documents the same
- instance the same 4vcpu і 32 ram.

Slower db stats:
[image]
Faster db stats:
[image]

As you can see slower db has bigger **"avgObjSize"** more than 10 times. And **"countDocuments({filter})"** with the same filter runs 10 times longer.

Еhere is some dependence on the  **avgObjSize(storageSize)** and counting documents? Or how I can speed up counting?

Comment: Are you trying to get a full count of the collection (meaning there is no filter being applied to the count)?

Comment: I apply filter on indexed field.

Comment: If the field was indexed, the query should be reading the index, not the documents, so the document size should not be relevant.